# Doing pivot with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I've got this problem..I have a CSV file in the following format (customer, bought item pair):

```
customer1 item1
customer1 item2
customer1 item3
customer2 item4
customer2 item2
customer3 item5
customer3 item1
customer3 item2
customer4 item1
customer4 item2
customer5 item5
customer5 item1
```

Now, I wish to show in query results:

```
item x; item y; how many customers have bought itemx and item together
```

For example:

```
item1 item2 3 (because cust1 and cust2 and cust3 bought item1 and item2 together)
item1 item5 1 (because cust5 and cust3 bought item1 and item5 together)
```

The query return all possible combinations of items that customers have bought in pairs. Also notice that Pair(x, y) is the same as Pair(y, x).

An SQL query would look like this:

```
SELECT a1.item_id, a2.item_id, COUNT(a1.cust_id) AS how_many_custs_bought_both
  FROM data AS a1
INNER JOIN data AS a2
  ON a2.cust_id=a1.cust_id AND a2.item_id<>a1.item_id AND a1.item_id<a2.item_id
GROUP BY a1.item_id, a2.item_id
```

How would you do that in C# 1) using regular for/foreach loops 2) using LINQ ?

I tried doing it in LINQ first but stuck when I noticed that LINQ doesn't support multiple equals keyword in join clause. Then I tried doing using normal loops, however, it became so unefficient that it could only process like 30 lines (of CSV file rows) per second.

Please advise!

Comment: where is your linq statement that you tried? also what is the delimiter of that .csv file. also why not put that query into a stored procedure or why not use `system.data.sqlclient` Class and use Parameterized queries..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ (and following the first 5 lines from Tim's answer) combining the chained method syntax with the query syntax for the join part:

```
var custItems =  new [] {
    new { customer = 1, item = 1 },
    new { customer = 1, item = 2 },
    new { customer = 1, item = 3 },
    new { customer = 2, item = 4 },
    new { customer = 2, item = 2 },
    new { customer = 3, item = 5 },
    new { customer = 3, item = 1 },
    new { customer = 3, item = 2 },
    new { customer = 4, item = 1 },
    new { customer = 4, item = 2 },
    new { customer = 5, item = 5 },
    new { customer = 5, item = 1 }
};
};

var pairs = custItems.GroupBy(x => x.customer)
         .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
         .Select(x =>  (from a in x.Select( y => y.item )
                        from b in x.Select( y => y.item )
                        where a < b //If you want to avoid duplicate (a,b)+(b,a)
                        // or just: where a != b, if you want to keep the dupes.
                        select new { a, b}))
         .SelectMany(x => x)
         .GroupBy(x => x)
         .Select(g => new { Pair = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
         .ToList();

pairs.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

**EDIT:** Forgot that OP wanted pair ocurrence count, added another .GroupBy() magic.

**EDIT:** Completed the example to show what it would output:

```
{ Pair = { a = 1, b = 2 }, Count = 3 }
{ Pair = { a = 1, b = 3 }, Count = 1 }
{ Pair = { a = 2, b = 3 }, Count = 1 }
{ Pair = { a = 2, b = 4 }, Count = 1 }
{ Pair = { a = 1, b = 5 }, Count = 2 }
{ Pair = { a = 2, b = 5 }, Count = 1 }
```

**EDIT:** rolled back and changed strings to integers, as OP shows a dataset with integers as IDs, and that removes the need for `.GetHashCode()`

Comment: Sorry, just found out, that this is not working after all. It doesn't output right information.

Comment: Hey @user315648, I've completed the example with the produced output. Why is it not working? Is it not what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry for being vague, it outputs duplicate information.

For example: (Item1, Item2) pairs is the same as (Item2, Item1).

That code above treats (a, b) different as (b, a), which is wrong..

Comment: Oh, you mean it actually should output duplicates. I will edit the answer (change `where a.GetHashCode() < b.GetHashCode()` to just `a != b`) I would delete my answer but the approach is different so maybe it's good if it stays.

Comment: Oh, damn sorry, I ment it treats (a, b) THE SAME as (b, a), which is wrong..

"where a != b" has nothing to do with it, it only removes (item1, item1) duplicates, but not (item1, item2) <=> (item2, item1) duplicates.

Comment: The CSVfile I'm working with is almost 9 MB large..could the problem be with GetHashCode ?

Comment: Well... the output is now certainly identical to your accepted answer. a != b avoids item1,item1, but also, in contras with the previous solution, treats a,b and b,a as different.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(csvFilePath);
var custItems = lines
    .Select(l => new { split = l.Split() })
    .Select(x => new { customer = x.split[0].Trim(), item = x.split[1].Trim() })
    .ToList();

var groups = from ci1 in custItems
             join ci2 in custItems
             on ci1.customer equals ci2.customer
             where ci1.item != ci2.item 
             group new { Item1 = ci1.item, Item2 = ci2.item } by new { Item1 = ci1.item, Item2 = ci2.item } into ItemGroup
             select ItemGroup;

var result = groups.Select(g => new
{
    g.Key.Item1,
    g.Key.Item2,
    how_many_custs_bought_both = g.Count()
});
```

Note that the materialization with `ToList` is important when the file is large because of the self-join.

```
{ Item1 = item1, Item2 = item2, how_many_custs_bought_both = 3 }
{ Item1 = item1, Item2 = item3, how_many_custs_bought_both = 1 }
{ Item1 = item2, Item2 = item1, how_many_custs_bought_both = 3 }
{ Item1 = item2, Item2 = item3, how_many_custs_bought_both = 1 }
{ Item1 = item3, Item2 = item1, how_many_custs_bought_both = 1 }
{ Item1 = item3, Item2 = item2, how_many_custs_bought_both = 1 }
{ Item1 = item4, Item2 = item2, how_many_custs_bought_both = 1 }
{ Item1 = item2, Item2 = item4, how_many_custs_bought_both = 1 }
{ Item1 = item5, Item2 = item1, how_many_custs_bought_both = 2 }
{ Item1 = item5, Item2 = item2, how_many_custs_bought_both = 1 }
{ Item1 = item1, Item2 = item5, how_many_custs_bought_both = 2 }
{ Item1 = item2, Item2 = item5, how_many_custs_bought_both = 1 }
```

Comment: That code also treats (item1, item2) different as (item2, item1), which is wrong. It outputs duplicates..

Comment: Sorry, it treats them THE SAME not different.

Answer (score 1):

You can write some like this:

```
IDictionary<int, int> pivotResult = customerItems.ToLookup(c => c.Customer)
                                 .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, y=>y.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

Working LINQ example, not too pretty!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Data
{
    public Data(int cust, int item)
    {
        item_id = item;
        cust_id = cust;
    }
    public int item_id { get; set; }
    public int cust_id { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<Data>
                       {new Data(1,1),new Data(1,2),new Data(1,3),
                        new Data(2,4),new Data(2,2),new Data(3,5),
                        new Data(3,1),new Data(3,2),new Data(4,1),
                        new Data(4,2),new Data(5,5),new Data(5,1)};

           (from a1 in data
            from a2 in data
            where a2.cust_id == a1.cust_id && a2.item_id != a1.item_id && a1.item_id < a2.item_id
            group new {a1, a2} by new {item1 = a1.item_id, item2 = a2.item_id}
            into g
            select new {g.Key.item1, g.Key.item2, count = g.Count()})
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",x.item1,x.item2,x.count))
            ;
           Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
1 3 1
2 3 1
2 4 1
1 5 2
2 5 1
```